# Swift empty array for loop

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

Execution is getting into the for-loop even when "objects" is empty. Am I crazy?

```
query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for object:PFObject? in objects! {
                //Do something
            }
        } else {
            NSLog("something's wrong")
        }
    })
```

Comment: It won't enter the `for` loop if error is empty, but how about `objects`? If `objects` is `nil` but so is `error`, it will enter the for loop.

Comment: Couldn't do objects? because it has to be unwrapped in order to use it in a loop like that. Didn't come across the case of objects being nil but it's good to know that it will enter the loop in that case. Thanks! I posted an answer too if you're interested.

Comment: You don't need an explicit type annotation in almost all cases, the compiler knows or is able to infer the proper type : `for object in objects! { …` In this case the annotation is even wrong, because the array contains non optional objects.

Comment: @vadian please see discussion below about OP's solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have been

```
for object:PFObject in objects!   //instead of "PFObject?"
```

Must have been because PFObject? is obtainable from an empty "objects" array with a value of nil and it gets in there. It also turns into an infinite loop. Tried PFObject! and it still gets in there as well...

Comment: You're right! In the playground, if you do, `var strs:[String]?
strs = ["foo","foo2", "foo3"]
for obj:String in strs!{
    print("Hi")
}` you will be fine - loop will run thrice. If you change it like you did to an optional or explicit cast, it enters an infinite loop. Can we get some input on this by a Swift expert?

Comment: Here's something I do know - an optional will take a nil value, so the `object:PFObject?` makes sense entering an infinite loop, but why `object:PFObject!`?

Comment: Yeah that was weird to me too. I was expecting a crash but it was still an infinite loop with `object` being nil...